# what is the Proper way to insert json into postgresql table?

Tags: json, python-3.x, create-table, postgresql-9.3, pgadmin-4

My json file looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "date": "2023-02-09",
    "homeTeam": {
      "id": "3",
      "players": [
        {
          "id": "5",
          "isInjured": "no",
          "shots": [
            { "Goal": "yes", "celebrated" : true},
            { "Goal": "yes", "celebrated" : true}
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I used python to load the data into psql database. How do i structure my table to insert data from python? I am not writting the data manualy, all the data is already in a json file.

How exactly do i insert into table using select?

My table currently looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS games(
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  , date DATE NOT NULL
  , homeTeam json
  , awayTeam json
);
```

I tried `json_populate_recordset(NULL::games, %s);` but it only inserts values to the first id and date.

Comment: I think that using json_populate records is the right way to go, the reason it doesn't insert homeTeam and awayTeam fields is probably because those fields have a json type. I suggest you look into replacing those fields with [array types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html) and [composite types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.